# Can you use the SUVAT equations of motion to draw a displacement-time graph?

Tags: kinematics, displacement

Can you use the SUVAT formulae of motion to draw a displacement time graph or should you integrate the graph you get from a velocity-time plot first? And why?

If i have

S = 4.4

U = 3

V = 1.4

A = -0.8

T = 2

can i therefore use the suvat equation : $s = t((u + v) /(2) )$ ?
this will give , s = 2.2t.
if i plot that, i will get a straight line. but if i use:
$s = ut + 0.5at^2$ , i will get $s= 3t + 0.5(-0.8)t^2 = s = 3t - 0.4t^2.$ this will give me an n-shaped curve which is clearly not the same. if , on the other hand, i integrate the graph that i got from plotting a velocity time graph, which was $v = -0.8t  + 3,$ i would get $s= -0.4t^2 + 3t + c,$ and this would be a completely different equation again. So what is wrong with the suvat equations method?

Comment: Hey, it would be really useful if you add '$' on both sides of an equation. Makes it much easier to the eyes.

Comment: okay, i didn't know that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard notation for suvat uses five lower-case letters: constants $a$ and $u$, a time parameter $t$, and two functions of it, $v=u+at$ and $s$, which has three equivalent formulae,$$ut+\tfrac12at^2=(u+v)t/2=vt-\tfrac12at^2.$$In your problem, you have specific values for five upper-case letters viz.$$U=u,\,A=a,\,V=v(t=T),\,S=s(t=T),$$so all your calculations are at a specific time. But we need the former, lower-case-variables insights to plot the behaviour at other times.

While $s=ut+\tfrac12at^2$ is true at all $t\in[0,\,T]$, $s=vt-\tfrac12at^2$ and $s=(u+v)t/2$ are only true for all such $t$ because we take $v=u+at=U+At$, and so $v=V=U+AT$ only works at $t=T$. So you can plot $s$ against $t$ from $t=0$ to $t=T$ with $s=ut+\tfrac12at^2$, so that$$s(t=0)=0,\,s(t=T)=S.$$

Comment: what do you mean by ''generality''?

Comment: @sweetiesakura I've edited. (Also, generality means [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Without_loss_of_generality), i.e. not requiring the assumption $t=T$.) Please delete any comments you feel I've addressed.

Comment: but you said that u and a were constants, so v varies according to time in v= U + At... so basically my only problem is with the v because it is a function as i learned from this, so it is a variable, so, what you're telling me is : i cannot use only one value of a variable to generalize the whole graph? .. im kind of confused.

Comment: @sweetie For example, $s=vt-At^2/2$ works (as does $S=VT-AT^2/2$), but $s=Vt-At^2/2$ doesn't. The former reduces by $v=U+At$ to $s=Ut+At^2/2$.

Comment: so for the first one you have 3 variables , namely, s, v and t.

Comment: but why can't u vary too? if you take u = U at t= 1 to be the initial, doesn't mean it can vary?

Comment: @sweetiesakura $u$ is defined as the velocity at $t=0$. The linear time evolution of velocity, $v=u+at$, has two degrees of freedom, each characterized by a constant parameter.

Comment: oh, then it stays a constant, like acceleration because the suvat equations of motion work only for constant acceleration..

Comment: i know this is a way later question and much time has passed since you answered my question but what do you mean by 'two degrees of freedom' for velocity?

Comment: @sweetiesakura I mean you need to know $u$ and $a$ to get $v$ as a function of $t$, and can determine them from $v$'s values at two distinct values of $t$.

Comment: i made a PDF version of this question-and-answer. download it here if you want to: https://www.mediafire.com/file/4fo5yql8ys29on9/Can+you+use+the+suvat+equations+of+motion+to+draw+a+displacement-time+graph-.pdf/file

Comment: check it out on my deviantart: https://www.deviantart.com/onrainyafternoons16/art/Can-you-use-suvat-to-draw-a-displacement-graph-986345496

Comment: hi. i don't know if you will receive this or not but there's something about this question that's been bugging me: what happens with the constant c ?

Comment: with the suvat method we got the equation : s=3t−0.4[t^2]

Comment: but with the integration method we got the equation s = 3t - 0.4 [t^2] + c

Comment: it's the first time im noticing that which is why im asking so late sorry

Comment: @sweetiesakura I set it to $0$ with the constraint $s(0)=0$. In other words, I defined $s$ as the displacement since $t=0$, which is the definite integral $\int_0^tv(t')dt'$. You can add a general constant to this by shifting the origin, so $s(0)$ becomes whatever additive integration constant you favour.

Comment: i dont understand. ive forgotten a lot about maths since i stopped studying it after my exam. could you be more clear please? use simpler words please.

Comment: i know that the function graph will be shifted certain units upwards or downwards if you add a constant c to the expression.

Comment: we know that on a displacement-time graph [ s(T) = S] s(0) = 0. so let's say c= 1, s(0) is no longer 0. so why is that constant even there?

Comment: ive made a graph for us to better understand. i chose the number 3 for c. https://1drv.ms/i/s!AjrBiy6hrWBEojMf8p43pbnPczdQ

Comment: @sweetiesakura Depending on how you use SUVAT equations, $s$ can tell you how far you travel without the $+c$ or where you end up with the $+c$. For the latter, you also need to say "by convention, this is where $s=0$ is". But if you choose it to be where you start, we still end up on the red curve instead of a green alternative.

Comment: well, im confused. ;/

Comment: could you please explain what you said: if you choose s=0 to be where you start we will still end up on the red curve? do you mean that the y-intercept doesn't really matter here? and why?

Comment: u cant graph the equation 3t-0.4tsquared plus c because of the c.

Comment: would you say that the suvat method is more accurate because of the absent c?

Answer (score 0):

You have integrated the velocity-time equation wrongly. Notice that, initial velocity $u = 3$ and acceleration is $a=-0.8$. Thus,

$v=u+at, $

$ v=3-0.8t$

You have written 2.6 in place of 3.

Integrate this, and you'll get

$ s = 3t - (0.8t^2)/2 $

Plot this graph. So, using the displacement equation and integrating the velocity equation gives you the same value.

In the case of your first technique, you cannot use that, as it only considers the initial and the final values of velocity. It doesn't account for the change in velocity between the two points, due to the negative acceleration. So, you either have to use the displacement equation or integrate the velocity equation.

Comment: oh, damn it, i will redo the question and upload it again...

Comment: Hey, its absolutely okay. Check if your answers match. If it does, I'd ask you to accept one of the answers here, as that would close the question. Else it would remain unsolved.

Answer (score 0):

Take the generic displacement function $s(t)$ and state what is known in terms of this function

$$ \begin{aligned}
& & \text{begin} & & \text{end} \\
\text{position}& &  s(0) & = 0 & s(T) & = S \\
\text{velocity}&  & s'(0)  &= U & s'(T) & = V \\
\text{acceleration} & & s''(0) &= A & s''(T) & = A
\end{aligned}$$

Now you have to decide how to parametrize the displacement. You mentioned two choices, linear and quadratic

$$\begin{aligned}
& \text{linear} & & \text{quadratic} \\
 s(t) & = c_0 + c_1 t & s(t) & = c_0 + c_1 t + c_2 t^2
\end{aligned}$$

Right of the bat you see that you cannot match the acceleration $A$ with the linear form, since $s''(t) =0$ for this case.

The problem with your expression  $S =T (U+V)/2 $  is that it  applies only at the end condition. At least the condition $V$ is defined for. It is not a general equation. What you wrote $S =t (U+V)/2$ is incorrect because it implies an arbitrary $t$. Again, this works only when $t=T$.

The correct form would be

$$ s(t) = t \left( \frac{U}{2} + \frac{U+A t}{2} \right) = U t + \tfrac{1}{2} A t^2$$

Answer (score 0):

A few points...

(a) The *suvat* equations apply only for constant (including zero) acceleration.

(b) It seems that you want use an equation to plot a displacement–time (s–t) graph. This is straightforward if (as is often the case) you know *u* and *a*; you plot your graph using $s=ut+\tfrac12 at^2$. If you have no given values for $t$ or $s$ you can treat these as variables and can take them as high as you like.

(c) Suppose, though, that you know $u$, $v$ and $t$. Clearly $t$ is not then a variable. If you know that $a$ is constant, then $s$ has the fixed value given by  $s=\frac12 (u+v)t$. All the same, you can plot a displacement–time graph for smaller or larger values of time than $t$, using $s'=ut'+\tfrac12 at'^2$, since you know that $a=(u-v)/t$. Why have we put dashes (primes) on $s$ and $t$? Because we mean something different: variables rather than the constant $s$ and $t$.